# Django internationalization for admin pages - translate model name and attributes

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-i18n

Django's internationalization is very nice (gettext based, LocaleMiddleware), but what is the proper way to translate the model name and the attributes for admin pages? I did not find anything about this in the documentation:

- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/internationalization/
- http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter19/

I would like to have "Выберите заказ для изменения" instead of "Выберите order для изменения". Note, the 'order' is not translated.

First, I defined a model, activated `USE_I18N = True` in settings.py, run `django-admin makemessages -l ru`. No entries are created by default for model names and attributes.

Grepping in the Django source code I found:

```
$ ack "Select %s to change"
contrib/admin/views/main.py
70:        self.title = (self.is_popup and ugettext('Select %s') % force_unicode(self.opts.verbose_name) or ugettext('Select %s to change') % force_unicode(self.opts.verbose_name))
```

So the `verbose_name` meta property seems to play some role here. Tried to use it:

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('order')
```

Now the updated `po` file contains `msgid 'order'` that can be translated. So I put the translation in. Unfortunately running the admin pages show the same mix of "Выберите order для изменения".

I'm currently using Django 1.1.1.
Could somebody point me to the relevant documentation? Because google can not. ;-) In the mean time I'll dig deeper into the django source code...

Comment: Sorry to ask, but after updating the .po file did you run ./manage.py makemessages to update the .mo file?

Comment: `makemessages` only updates the po files. I think
you mean `django-admin compilemessages` - thank
you for your hint! I thought because python is a
dynamic language, the translation files are not
compiled, in opposite to C. 


Unfortunately my solution still does not work
delivering a mixed translation (languages are
mixed in one sentence). For model name the
LANGUAGE_CODE setting of the project is used. The
language for remaining message is determined by
the User Agent ('Accept-Languages'). I'll
experiment with lazy translation and tell if it
works.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Important things not mentioned in the Django documentation:

- run `django-admin compilemessages`, e.g. as a part of your build
  process. Thanks stevejalim!
- apply django's `ugettext_lazy()` to model names ( `Meta` class and `verbose_name` )
- attribute (model field `verbose_name`) names can also be translated with `ugettext_lazy()`
- use lazy translation in your model metadata, otherwise the translation
  happens while loading the model classes and the settings of your users,
  especially the browser settings, will not be taken into account
- I use some scoping for attribute names, e.g. separating the model name
  and attribute names with a pipe. The same convention is used in
  ruby-gettext. Background: attribute names like 'title' or 'name' translated
  differently in the most languages depending on context. Example
  'Book|title' -> 'Titel' or 'Buchtitel' in German. But
  'Chapter|title' would be translated as 'Überschrift'.

Example using above principles:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
class Order(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name = _('Order|subject'))
    description = models.TextField(            verbose_name = _('Order|description'))
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('order')
        verbose_name_plural = _('orders')
```

Or is there a better way to translate the model and admin pages?

Either way we should enhance the Django documentation and fill the gap!

Comment: I am using ugettext_lazy, but unfortunantly is doesn't works for me.

Comment: I've done all this, but still can't get model names & fields to be translated

Comment: I'm facing the same problem as @M. Dhaouadi. 
I've done all this, but still can't get model names & fields to be translated.

Comment: If remove "#, fuzzy" string from generating by "makemessages" locale file - it is work for me! I think Django try to optimise some words in translation and we need to check it manual.

Comment: This is beautiful!, i love you

Comment: @break1 is right. I also removed `#, fuzzy` then, a model label is translated successfully.

Answer (score 2):

See https://automationpanda.com/2018/04/21/django-admin-translations/
It's author made an excellent work in showing how to master all django translation features step by step. It's much better than oficial documentation to me.

Answer (score 1):

I also couldn't translate a model label in Django Admin because there are `#, fuzzy` in `django.po` as shown below:

```
# "django.po"

...

#: .\my_app1\models.py:12
#, fuzzy # <- Here
msgid "person"
msgstr "personne"

#: .\my_app1\models.py:13
#, fuzzy # <- Here
msgid "persons"
msgstr "personnes"

...
```

So, I removed `#, fuzzy` from `django.po` as shown below, then I could translate the model label in Django Admin. *You can see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76492319/cannot-translate-only-a-model-label-in-django-admin) and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76492319/cannot-translate-only-a-model-label-in-django-admin/76492320#76492320) explaining it in detail:

```
# "django.po"

...

#: .\my_app1\models.py:12
msgid "person"
msgstr "personne"

#: .\my_app1\models.py:13
msgid "persons"
msgstr "personnes"

...
```

In addition, [fuzzy](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/PO-Files.html#index-fuzzy-flag) is explained in [the doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/PO-Files.html) as shown below:

> fuzzy
>
> This flag can be generated by the msgmerge program or it can be inserted by the translator herself. It shows that the msgstr string might not be a correct translation (anymore). Only the translator can judge if the translation requires further modification, or is acceptable as is. Once satisfied with the translation, she then removes this fuzzy attribute. The msgmerge program inserts this when it combined the msgid and msgstr entries after fuzzy search only. See Fuzzy Entries.

Answer (score 0):

I use both ugettext with `_` and ugettext_lazy with a double `__`. Consequently, the `makemessages` management command was only collecting the first ones.

To collect both `_` and `__` we can ask the `gettext` tool to collect more than the default strings enclosed in `_( )`. To do this, we override the `makemessages` command: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#customizing-the-makemessages-command

```py
# myapp/management/commands/makemessages.py
from django.core.management.commands import makemessages

class Command(makemessages.Command):
    self.stdout.write("----> Using our custom makemessages command to collect both _ and double __")
    xgettext_options = makemessages.Command.xgettext_options + ['--keyword=__']  # <-- added __
```

My models in Admin are now finally fully translated.