# How to translate the application label in Django CMS Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-cms, django-i18n

How can I translate the application label in the Django CMS admin?

See the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you asking where is it being translated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer below was correct for Django 1.4 or 1.5, I believe. For more modern answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32431808/1067717

---

Have a look at [this previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938692/django-internationalization-for-admin-pages-translate-model-name-and-attribute) on the similar topic for internationalization in Django.

Internally, it uses [`Model._meta.app_label`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label) to display the application name. Inspect [admin view](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L386) and [its template](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/index.html#L19-L23) for further information.

Comment: Thanks Seyeong! Changing the meta.app_label will change also the database name - something I want to avoid, but seems that there is no other choice.

Comment: This answer doesn't work. For solution use @nik_m 's answer

Answer (score 35):

***UPDATE:*** For Django 3+ import `gettext_lazy` instead of `ugettext_lazy`. Like this:

```py
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
```

---

OK. I have found how to translate the app name without changing the database name.
Example (inside `apps.py` of app you want to translate):

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'MyApp'
    verbose_name = _('Transalation of MyApp here')
```

Run `makemessages -a` and after altering `django.po` run `compilemessages` and you are done. Hit refresh in admin and your app name is translated.

Comment: While this works sometimes, it doesn't all the time. I'm having a problem where only SOME of my app names are getting translated, and even though I have a verbose name assigned, it still doesn't get translated in the site. I have five apps in my project and three of them are not translating.

Comment: @Nathan. Hm... I think you should make a new question and show some code. Otherwise it'll be difficult to help you from the comments section!

Comment: @Nathan You are probably missing `default_app_config = 'myapp.apps.MyAppConfig'` in your `__init__.py`

Comment: @dmcontador I figured it out, but this was quit ea long time ago and i forgot what I did to fix it! ha

Comment: You still need to add the app to INSTALLED_APPS using the AppConfig class:
```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  ...
  'MyApp.apps.MyAppConfig'
  
  ...
]
```

Comment: "ugettext_lazy" should be "gettext_lazy"

Answer (score 4):

It might too late to answer this question but i am sharing my experience.

Add below mention code to model.py

```
VERBOSE_NAME = _('Appname')
```

After the use this

```
django-admin.py makemessages -a
django-admin.py compilemessages
```

This will add entry to django.po.

Comment: Are you saying about model Meta class or App Name?

Comment: Its Model Meta class

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which CMS you used,so I just give you a sample code below. Maybe you can change the fields in your models.py file like this:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    title         = models.CharField(u'标题',max_length=300)

    # other fields here
```

[image: pic]

The code above is work well in my project(django 1.4.2),the first param(string) in CharField() will display in my Admin view,I think it is useful for you.

The full code in my project:https://github.com/tianyu0915/pythoner.net/blob/master/pythoner/wiki/models.py#L69

Answer (score 0):

I use **Django 4.2.1** and for example, you can translate an application label by adding [verbose_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.verbose_name) to `MyAppConfig` class in `my_app/apps.py` as shown below. *You should use [gettext_lazy()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext_lazy) instead of [gettext()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.translation.gettext) otherwise there is an error and you can see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467626/whats-the-correct-way-to-set-up-django-translation/76475418#76475418) explaining how to translate in Django:

```py
# "my_app/apps.py"

from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'my_app'
    verbose_name = _('my_app') # Here
```

Then, `my_app` is translated to `nom_app` in French in yellow as shown below. *I don't know how to translate the model label `persons` in blue:

[image]