# Translate app name in django-admin-tools menu

Tags: python, django, internationalization, django-admin, django-admin-tools

How can I translate app name in django-admin-tools?

[image: translate app name]

I try to do this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/ and it translate app name in standard django admin, but not in django-admin-tools

Comment: Please try to google search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168671/how-to-translate-the-application-name-in-django-cms-admin

Comment: See here if you are using Django >= 1.7 : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/

Comment: OP is referring to the auto-generated menu created by third party add-on django-admin-tools, not the default django admin, to the folks that downvoted this question and linked to incorrect answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/) didn't work, because django-admin-tools didn't use model._meta.app_config.verbose_name or internationalization in menu. I found this [patch](https://bitbucket.org/izi/django-admin-tools/issues/158/use-app_configverbose_name-in-menu) and it's solved my problem.

Comment: Can you put the solution here? The "patch" link not exists more.

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20200621211631/https://bitbucket.org/izi/django-admin-tools/issues/158/use-app_configverbose_name-in-menu