# Only a model label is not translated in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-i18n

I'm trying to translate the entire Django Admin from **English** to **French**.

This is my `django-project` below. *I use **Django 4.2.1**:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  |-settings.py
 |  └-urls.py
 |-my_app1
 |  |-models.py
 |  |-admin.py
 |  └-apps.py
 |-my_app2
 └-locale
    └-fr
       └-LC_MESSAGES
          |-django.po
          └-django.mo
```

And, this is `core/settings.py` below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('fr', _('French'))
)
```

And, this is `core/urls.py` below:

```py
# "core/urls.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
)
```

And, this is `my_app1/models.py` below:

```py
# "my_app1/models.py"

from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name=_("name"))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('person')
        verbose_name_plural = _('persons')
```

And, this is `my_app1/apps.py` below:

```py
# "my_app1/apps.py"

from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class MyApp1Config(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'my_app1'
    verbose_name = _('my_app1')
```

And, this is `locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po` below:

```
# "locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po"

...

#: .\core\settings.py:140
msgid "English"
msgstr "Anglais"

#: .\core\settings.py:141
msgid "French"
msgstr "Français"

#: .\my_app1\apps.py:7
msgid "my_app1"
msgstr "mon_app1"

#: .\my_app1\models.py:6
msgid "name"
msgstr "nom"

#: .\my_app1\models.py:12
#, fuzzy
msgid "person"
msgstr "personne"

#: .\my_app1\models.py:13
#, fuzzy
msgid "persons"
msgstr "personnes"

...
```

But, only the model label `person` is not translated at `http://localhost:8000/fr/admin/my_app1/person/add/` as shown below:

[image]

So, how can I translate the model label `person`?

Answer (score 0):

You should comment `#, fuzzy` out by adding one more `#` to the front or completely remove them in `locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po` as shown below:

```
# "locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/django.po"

...

#: .\core\settings.py:140
msgid "English"
msgstr "Anglais"

#: .\core\settings.py:141
msgid "French"
msgstr "Français"

#: .\my_app1\apps.py:7
msgid "my_app1"
msgstr "mon_app1"

#: .\my_app1\models.py:6
msgid "name"
msgstr "nom"

#: .\my_app1\models.py:12
##, fuzzy # <- Here
msgid "person"
msgstr "personne"

#: .\my_app1\models.py:13
##, fuzzy # <- Here
msgid "persons"
msgstr "personnes"

...
```

Then, run the command below:

```
django-admin compilemessages
```

Now, `http://localhost:8000/fr/admin/my_app1/person/add/` can also translate the model label `person` as shown below:

[image]

In addition, [fuzzy](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/PO-Files.html#index-fuzzy-flag) is explained in [the doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/PO-Files.html) as shown below:

> fuzzy
>
> This flag can be generated by the msgmerge program or it can be inserted by the translator herself. It shows that the msgstr string might not be a correct translation (anymore). Only the translator can judge if the translation requires further modification, or is acceptable as is. Once satisfied with the translation, she then removes this fuzzy attribute. The msgmerge program inserts this when it combined the msgid and msgstr entries after fuzzy search only. See Fuzzy Entries.

Comment: In my case locale path was missing `LOCALE_PATHS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "locale"),)`  as shown [link](https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/django-admin-interface/issues/115#issuecomment-808725775)